# JQuery - Clone a select element, filter desired option elements and append to another select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web page of an application on which there are two select elements **(among other)**. Initially, both select elements will have values. Note specially that second select element will have full set of values to begin with. The requirement is for the content of second select to reduce to a subset based on what user has select in the first select element. Since I need to retain the initial content of the second select, I first clone it in document.ready().

Let us say following is the initial second select element

```
<select id="sid">
<option value="0" selected="">Unknown</option>
<option value="1">Unit</option>
<option value="2">House</option>
<option value="3">Apartment</option>
</select>
```

How could I create a clone and remove 'Unknown' and 'Apartment' from the object and append it back to the select having run empty() to clear the options first.

So far I have come with following. Looking for some information what could go in the function passed to filter (see comment **//need logic to filter option with value Unknown and Apartment**)

```
var toRetain = $('#sid').clone();
$('#sid').empty();
var secondClone = toRetain .clone()
$('option', secondClone).each(function(i){console.log(i));}); // able to print all options
$('option', secondClone).filter(function(i){
    //need logic to filter option with value Unknown and Apartment
}).remove()

$('#sid').append(b.html())
```

Comment: you can add specific *classes* to your *option-tags* and refer to those classes in manipulating them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the options you want to remove are always in the same positions you could use `:eq()` to select and remove them, no need to `empty()` the entire set:

```js
var $toRetain = $('#sid').clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo('body');
$toRetain.find('option:eq(0), option:eq(3)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sid">
  <option value="0" selected="">Unknown</option>
  <option value="1">Unit</option>
  <option value="2">House</option>
  <option value="3">Apartment</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively you could use `:first` and `:last`, or even add a specific `class` on them to select by. In any case the pattern would be the same; identify the `option` to be removed and call `remove()` on them.

If you need to select them by their text content then you can do that using `filter()`:

```js
let toRemove = ['Unknown', 'Apartment'];

var $toRetain = $('#sid').clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo('body');
$toRetain.find('option').filter((i, el) => toRemove.indexOf(el.textContent.trim()) != -1).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sid">
  <option value="0" selected="">Unknown</option>
  <option value="1">Unit</option>
  <option value="2">House</option>
  <option value="3">Apartment</option>
</select>
```

Also note that I used `removeAttr()` to remove the `id` from the cloned content, as `id` attributes must always be unique within the DOM.

Comment: this is not an option as I need to apply some logic to determine which options should be taken off based on the innerHTML ('Unknown' in this case)

Comment: Just updated the answer with that approach :)

Comment: Nice, I found a slight variation of this, accepting your answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Following code too achieves the desired

```
var toRetain = $('#sid').clone();
$('#sid').empty();
var secondClone = toRetain .clone()
$('option', secondClone).each(function(i){console.log(i));}); // able to print all options
$('option', secondClone).filter(function(i){
    return  ['Unknown', 'Apartment'].indexOf($(this).html()) != -1;
}).remove()

$('#sid').append(b.html())
```